# Slider (Binded value) does not update probably when using custom binding that needs casting (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

before I show you som could I want to explain my problem first.
I have a `SettingsViewModel` holding one variable with a protocol type called `Settings`. I initialize this one with some `SpecificSetting`. In my `SettingsView` I have a `SpecificSettingsView`, which is visible if I have SpecificSettings. As I need to cast this and don't want an optional I need a custom binding to pass to my subview, which allows modifying the settings. Editing is done via 2 Sliders and if I edit `someValue` `someOtherValue` should be increased by `someValue + 5`. But especially if I drag the sliders fast this is not true.

Here is the code if you want to check it out:
The protocol and model:

```
protocol Settings {}
struct SpecificSettings: Settings {
    var someValue: Double
    var someOtherValue: Double
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Can be initialized with any value
    @Published var settings: Settings = SpecificSettings(someValue: 5, someOtherValue: 10)
    
    // I dont have this property in my actual code
    @Published var specificSettings = SpecificSettings(someValue: 5, someOtherValue: 10)
}
```

The SettingView:
I also added a code snippet that does work. Without casting the settings to a SpecificSetting it would work. But I can not do this in my actual code base.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let specificSettings = viewModel.settings as? SpecificSettings {
                let specificSettingBinding = Binding {
                    specificSettings
                } set: { newSpecificSettings, _ in
                    viewModel.settings = newSpecificSettings
                }
                // cast settings and pass a custom binding -> does not work
                SpecificSettingsView(specificSettings: specificSettingBinding)
            }
            Divider()
                .padding(30)
            // directly pass specific settings without custom binding and casting -> Works
            SpecificSettingsView(specificSettings: $viewModel.specificSettings)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The EditView for the specific settings:

```
struct SpecificSettingsView: View {
    @Binding var specificSettings: SpecificSettings
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(specificSettings.someValue.description)
            Slider(value: $specificSettings.someValue,
                   in: 0 ... 100)
            
            Text(specificSettings.someOtherValue.description)
            Slider(value: $specificSettings.someOtherValue,
                   in: 0 ... 100)
        }
        .onChange(of: specificSettings.someValue) { newValue in
            specificSettings.someOtherValue = newValue + 5
        }
    }
}
```

You can already experience the issue in the preview:

```
struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by modifying my `SpecificSettingsView`. Instead of the `onChange()` modifier I used a second custom binding to make my adjustments inside the setter:

```
struct SpecificSettingsView: View {
    @Binding var specificSettings: SpecificSettings

    private var customBinding: Binding<SpecificSettings> {
        Binding {
            specificSettings
        } set: { newSettings in
            var newSettings = newSettings
            newSettings.someOtherValue = newValue + 5
            specificSettings = newSettings
        }
    }
            
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(specificSettings.someValue.description)
            Slider(value: customBinding.someValue,
                   in: 0 ... 100)
            
            Text(specificSettings.someOtherValue.description)
            Slider(value: customBinding.someOtherValue,
                   in: 0 ... 100)
        }
    }
}
```